# Как заново запустить анимацию?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

пример проблемы - перешли на второй слайд

потом возвращаемся на первый - title выдает не 1, а 3 или 4.

Тоесть анимация идет не сначала (функция анимации textRotator)

https://jsbin.com/gezamubene/10/edit?html,js,output